# CSS Text Layout/Formatting Problem

Tags: css, text, formatting, shift

So I have large blocks of text in my website, but right now the default in CSS is left, so all the text is aligned to the left. However, say I want to shift all the text to the right by 100 pixels. How do I accomplish this in CSS? (what kind of function should I add?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, but is `padding-left:100px`  or `margin-left:100px` in the CSS that you're looking for ?